# Change text and image opacity in figure

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a figure with icon and text. Both of them should redirect to some page when clicked.
Also I want to change opacity of image and text when you hover on them.
However I have a problem... The text area seems bigger than image area.

This is the code where I change the opacity:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buyText").hover(function() {
        $('#buy').css('opacity', 0.75);
        $("#buyText").css('opacity', 0.75);
    }, function() {
        $('#buy').css('opacity', 1);
        $("#buyText").css('opacity', 1);
    });
});

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#buy").hover(function() {
            $('#buy').css('opacity', 0.75);
            $("#buyText").css('opacity', 0.75);
        }, function() {
            $('#buy').css('opacity', 1);
            $("#buyText").css('opacity', 1);
        });
    });
```

I created the fiddle as an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lk9af87t/

If you approach to text from left side lets say, the text's opacity changes, but the image remains with the same. How can I assure that both of them change opacity at same time (on hover).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `#buy` and `#buyText` elements are different sizes, so their `mouseenter` events will fire at different times. If you want both to be affected at the same time use a parent element instead, such as the `a`.

Also note that you can make this logic work more succinctly, and with better performance, using CSS:

```
a.buy-link:hover #buy,
a.buy-link:hover #buyText {
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```css
a.buy-link:hover #buy,
a.buy-link:hover #buyText {
  opacity: 0.75;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: rgb(0, 151, 224);
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: rgb(84, 195, 241);
}
```

```html
<div class="col text-center">
  <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none" class="buy-link">
    <figure>
      <img id="buy" src="https://banner2.kisspng.com/20180418/ixe/kisspng-agar-io-computer-icons-ubuntu-skin-buy-5ad7236a419759.6594585115240487462687.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
      <figcaption id="buyText" style="margin-top: 10px"><b>BUY</b></figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this css code

```
.text-center a {margin: 20px;display: block;}
.text-center figure {margin: 0;}
```

Comment: You want both the image and text should change opacity at the same time.
This css code for anchor tag a will contain figure tag and thus on figure hover both image and text will change opacity at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to CSS

```
a:hover {
    color: rgb(84, 195, 241);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The area of the link element is greater than the figure (which, by default, has a margin applied). What is actually changing is not the opacity but the color

[image]

So either you remove that rule on hover, or you remove the margin applied on the `figure` element

---

As a side note I'd suggest to not use JS for this kind of task. You could apply the same effect via CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want to avoid JQuery and use CSS only solution, change your CSS to:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
}

/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: rgb(0, 151, 224);
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
    color: rgb(0, 151, 224);
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: rgb(84, 195, 241);
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 0.75
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
    color: rgb(0, 151, 224);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```